# Check if a string constant is contained in a set of strings

Tags: delphi, set, delphi-10.4-sydney

What is the best and most SIMPLE way to do this in modern Delphi (Sydney):

```
var ThisExtension: string;
if ThisExtension in ['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.jpe', '.jif', '.jfif'] then
```

The above code gives me this compiler error:

```
E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
```

Comment: Do you also need an explanation about the compiler error?

Comment: Define best please

Comment: Another option is given in the linked-to question...

Comment: The answer in the proposed SO question "Set Of String??!!" does not nearly meet the required criteria of simplicity as much as MatchText does: A `type` must be declared AND a `constant` must be declared AND a `variable` must be declared etc. On the other hand, `System.StrUtils.MatchText` is a simple and fast one-liner.

Comment: Who has closed the question? The same HATERS as always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.StrUtils` unit has a simple function for this:

```
if System.StrUtils.MatchText(ThisExtension, ['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.jpe', '.jif', '.jfif']) then
```

I don't know whether this is the most modern approach. (Maybe `Generics` has a better approach?). But it is fast and simple.

Comment: Note that `MatchText()` is case-insensitive. If you want a case-sensitive comparison, use [`MatchStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StrUtils.MatchStr) instead.

Comment: Who needs case sensitivity when comparing file extensions?

Comment: Not all file systems are case-insensitive.

Comment: Yes, this is the best modern way IMHO. You can also declare a constant `const
  PictureExts: TArray<string> = ['.bmp', '.png', '.jpg', '.gif'];` and use that.

Comment: The possibility of declaring an expression like `TArray<string> = ['.bmp', '.png', '.jpg', '.gif']` as a constant is an ingenious simplification in `Generics`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Could you please write an answer with an `if` condition using `TArray<string> = ['.bmp', '.png', '.jpg', '.gif']` so I can accept it?

Comment: @user1580348: I could, but I wouldn't feel good about it because that answer would essentially be the same as your answer but with a tiny difference! (Essentially: `A(12, 13)` vs. `C := 13; A(12, C)`.) You can accept your own answer, and anyone can read my comment about the fairly new Delphi possibility to create dynamic array constants.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I can accept my own answer only 10 hours from now. Meanwhile, some unknown person has closed my question (!) although I have clearly stated in a comment that the proposed alternative answer does not meet the criteria of my question! This is very strange! There are strange people here on SO...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand When I try to declare a constant like in your example: `const   PictureExts: TArray<string> = ['.bmp', '.png', '.jpg', '.gif'];` then I get a compiler error: `E2086 Type 'TArray<T>' is not yet completely defined`

Comment: @user1580348: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Delphi 10.4.2. However, when I declare `array of string` instead then it works.

Comment: @user1580348: I assume you are declaring the `const` as a member of a class or record type? Because the syntax works for (1) global constants, (2) local constants, and (3) inline-local constants, but not for member constants. I consider this a bug in the Delphi compiler.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You are right: When I declare it as an inline/local constant then it works. However, meanwhile, I solved the problem by using `array of string` as a class member instead.

Comment: [System.StrUtils.IndexText] (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.StrUtils.IndexText)

`IndexText(ThisExtension, ['.jpeg', '.jpg', '.jpe', '.jif', '.jfif']) >= 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the simplest or most elegant, but you can use a `TStringList`, eg:

```pascal
var
  Exts: TStringList;

procedure InitExtensions;
begin
  Exts := TStringList.Create;
  Exts.CaseSensitive := ...; // false by default
  Exts.Add('.jpeg');
  Exts.Add('.jpg');
  Exts.Add('.jpe');
  Exts.Add('.jif');
  Exts.Add('.jfif');
end;

...

var
  ThisExtension: string;
begin
  ...
  if Exts.IndexOf(ThisExtension) <> -1 then
  begin
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;

...

initialization
  InitExtensions;
finalization
  Exts.Free;
end.
```

Comment: That does not meet the criteria of simplicity as much as `MatchText` does.

Comment: I would use `try-end-finally`.

Comment: @user1580348 Sure, if the `TStringList` is a local variable, but that is actually not what I intended. I have updated my example